# Import and Plot MS Excel file in ArcGIS (v9.3) ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-9.3, modelbuilder, import

I am trying to create a tool using ArcGIS ModelBuilder (v9.3) that will allow me to import an Excel file, and output it as a shapefile in a coordinate system of my choice - or, if choosing the CRS is not an option, in WGS84.

I have set the input dataset (as part of the model), but can't seem to find a tool to facilitate the import. I have an ArcView licence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ArcGIS 10 there is a toolbox called **Make XY Event Layer**. It's found in **Data Management Tools > Layers and Table Views** in the main Arc Toolbox. This creates a temporary layer that you should be able to export to a feature class.

I don't have 9.3 to test, but I think the same tool is available in that version.

Comment: Thanks Kevin - the tool does exist in 9.3 and the model is working fine; thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can import your xls file into Model Builder using the Make XY Evemt Layer tool.  You can then use the Feature Class to Feature Class tool to convert the event layer to a shapefile.